# General cohomology groups and motives

Tags: langlands-conjectures, etale-cohomology, motives

Let $X$ be a variety over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf on $X$. Then we have an action of $Gal(\mathbb{Q})$ on $H_{et}^i(X,\mathcal{F})$. In certain cases we can say a lot about this action. For example if $\mathcal{F}$ is the constant sheaf $\mathbb{Q}_ p$ for some prime $p$, or the constant sheaf $\mathbb{C}$. In those cases $H_{et}^*(\ \underline{},\mathcal{F})$ is a Weil cohomology; and so we conjecture that these representations come from motives, and in particular we have the Langlands conjectures about how these representations are ``nice'' (i.e. automorphic).

My question is: what can we say about the representation $H_{et}^i(X,\mathcal{F})$ for a general $\mathcal{F}$? What if $\mathcal{F}$ is, for example, not constant? Do we have an equivalent conjecture to the Langlands conjectures? (i.e. is there a generalization for a general $\mathcal{F}$ to the statement that $H_{et}^i(X,\mathcal{F})$ should be automorphic?)

My humility when it comes to the Langlands conjectures behooved me to put a community wiki stamp on this question on the off chance my question strikes experts as silly and/or vague.

Comment: The setup here, strictly speaking, is not correct.  The sheaves which give rise to etale cohomology are sheaves on the etale site of X, not on X itself.  Furthermore, etale cohomology with $\mathbf{Q}_p$-coefficients is defined as the inverse limit of etale cohomology groups with coefficients in $\mathbf{Z}/p^i\mathbf{Z}$, tensored with $\mathbf{Q}_p$.  I believe that $\mathbf{Q}_p$- or $\mathbf{C}$-coefficients yield groups which are usually identically zero.  The analogue of "nonconstant sheaf" in this setting might be something like "lisse $\ell$-adic sheaf", but I am far from an expert.

Comment: Hmm... I was careless with my speech. You are right that I meant $\mathcal{F}$ as sheaf on the etale site on $X$ rather than $X$. (I viewed that as implicit by the fact that I look at $H_{et}^*(X,\mathcal{F})$.) Your other comment is more substantive -- is it true that $H^i_{et}(X,\mathbb{Q}_p)$ where $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is the constant sheaf on the etale site over $X$ is different from the inverse limit of the $H^i_{et}(X,\mathbb{Z}/p^i\mathbb{Z})$? 

Comment: The computation of "naive etale cohomology" as you give it here is on page 118 of my copy of Freitag-Kiehl; as David Hansen states, with $\mathbb{Q}_p$ coefficients, all higher cohomology vanishes.  The right thing here is not etale cohomology, but rather $\ell$-adic cohomology.  FK also gives the naive computation for $\mathbb{Z}_p$ coefficients, which is pretty interesting, actually.  One reason to think that this inverse limit gives the "right thing" is that one expects $H^1$ to be dual to the $\ell$-adic Tate module for an elliptic curve, and the naive definition doesn't work here, whereas

Comment: (cont.) $\ell$-adic definition does work.

Comment: I'm not sure if lisse l-adic sheaf is really what I would be looking for. Ideally, I would like a statement that would also make sense for $\mathcal{F}$ a linear algebraic group scheme (which would restrict us to non-abelian cohomology), although that might be asking too much. For now it would suffice to restrict ourselves to sheaves into abelian groups.

Comment: @James:  It's probably worth working through the usual $\ell$-adic theory yourself before trying to get fancy with non-abelian stuff--even doing things properly with torsion coefficients (e.g. the constant sheaf $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$) is pretty contentful.  Also, I feel like "what can we say about this" is a bit broad--could you give a (true) statement about some easier case, e.g. $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients, so we know what sort of thing  you're really looking for?

Comment: @Daniel: that's a very good point. Does $H^i(X,\mathbb{Q}_p)$ being automorphic imply anything of any content about the representation $H^i(X,\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})$?

Comment: @James:  I don't really know anything about that side of things, so I can't tell you (at least at finite level, one can find a stable lattice and reduce mod some power of the uniformizer in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ to get a $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$-rep, but I don't see what this buys you).  I was hoping you had some particular result in mind you were thinking to generalize.

Comment: @Daniel: Alas, I did not. My understanding of Langlands is rudimentary at best. I was trying to place Langlands, which is a statement about Galois actions on certain groups coming from schemes, in the context of general Galois actions on groups coming from schemes. 


Comment: Okay, I am inclined to close this question.  It looks like a fishing expedition.

Comment: @S. Carnahan: I agree, MO should not be the first place one comes to for this sort of question.  Voting to close.

Comment: I vote to close as well.

Comment: @Daniel: While I agree that this seems to have no clear answer and is therefore worthy of closing down, I completely disagree that MO should not be the first place to go to with this sort of question. It is precisely the collective knowledge of mathematicians that I want to tap into. There is clearly no book about this; if there are papers about it they would be hard to find; and if individuals don't know the answer it doesn't mean that an answer doesn't exist. This is precisely what mathoverflow is for. 

Comment: @James:  There are plenty of books and papers about the subjects in your question, and even just a quick search of MO would reveal many references.  For $\ell$-adic cohomology, try Freitag-Kiehl and Brian Conrad's notes; for motivic stuff there have been several MO questions with lists of references; for Langlands stuff there are many surveys, some written from a motivic point of view--really all of the aspects of your question have pretty rich literature surrounding them.